# SQL View / Function Select statement changes based on Database Connection

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where my production and development (and QA too) databases all have different names.  The application uses Views to reference tables in other databases.  Rather than having separate scripts in source control for each (dev, qa, production) I'd like to create one 'master' script (view or function?) which will run on all but will select against the appropriate database based upon where (current database) it is run from.

Something like:

```
CASE db_name() 
WHEN 'dev' THEN (SELECT a,b... FROM DEVSERVER.DEVOTHERDB.dbo.mytable)
WHEN 'prod' THEN (SELECT a,b... FROM PRODSERVER.PRODOTHERDB.dbo.mytable)
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Database Synonyms sometimes help in this situation - or make the problem worse.  In an Azure SQL World - cross database or switching database/catalog doesn't really work.

Comment: "The application uses Views to reference tables in other databases" Do you really need to link a production database with a dev database? This doesn't sound right. You should use the same view and just connect to different database.

Comment: @EzLo I'm trying to avoid separate scripts for separate databases.  The SQL is different in each situation due to the servername.databasename combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, the first thing you run is

```
If Object_Id('dbo.CreateSynonym') Is Not Null Drop Procedure dbo.CreateSynonym
Go

Create Procedure dbo.CreateSynonym
  @TableName SysName
As
Begin
  Declare @Sql NVarchar(Max) = 'If Exists(Select * From sys.synonyms where name = ''' + @TableName + ''''
  Exec (@Sql)

  Set @Sql = 'Create Synonym dbo.' + @TableName + ' For ' +
     Case When Db_Name() = 'dev' Then 'devserver.devdb' 
          When Db_Name() = 'prod' Then 'prodserver.proddb' End + '.dbo.' + @TableName 

  Exec (@Sql)
End

Go

Exec dbo.CreateSynonym 'mytable'
Exec dbo.CreateSynonym 'myothertable'
...
...
Go
```

(From the top of my head, might have warts)
From then on, you just reference `dbo.MyTable`.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` cannot return a resultset, but only one value.
What you can do is write entire different sql for each db

```
declare @DBName varchar(100)
select @DBName = db_name()

if @DBName = 'dev'
begin
     SELECT a,b... FROM DEVSERVER.DEVOTHERDB.dbo.mytable
end
else if @DBName = 'prod'
begin
     SELECT a,b... FROM PRODSERVER.PRODOTHERDB.dbo.mytable
end
```

another option is using [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)

```
declare @DBName varchar(100)
select @DBName = db_name()
declare @sql varchar(max)

if @DBName = 'dev'
begin
     set @sql = 'SELECT a,b... FROM DEVSERVER.DEVOTHERDB.dbo.mytable'
end
else if @DBName = 'prod'
begin
     set @sql = 'SELECT a,b... FROM PRODSERVER.PRODOTHERDB.dbo.mytable'
end

exec (@sql)
```